# Programmatically opening Kube CSS Framework Message Alert

Tags: javascript, kube-css

How do I open a message alert from javascript?

I have my div defined below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="message success" id="cart-message-success"><p>Added to cart</p></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
 $('#cart-message-success').message('open');
```

And when I try to open it through javascript as below, I get the error message as illustrated below:

> Error: No such method "open" for message

How do I make the call correctly?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="message success" id="cart-message-success" style="display: none;">Added to cart</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#cart-message-success').fadeIn(200);
```